# Installing an older CU over a Security Patch?

Tags: sql-server, cumulative-update

According to [this Microsoft link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4535288/description-of-the-security-update-for-sql-server-2014-sp3-cu4-feb), SQL Server 12.0.6372.1 requires any system with at least SQL 2014 SP3, so my predecessor installed it over SP3.  Now the version is "2014 (SP3-CU-GDR) (KB4535288) - 12.0.6372.1".

Since that security patch only fixes a specific problem with Reporting Services, and is smaller than the CU4 package, ISTM that I should also install the CU4 patch.

But how?  Do I first uninstall KB4535288, then install KB4500181 (CU4) and then reinstall KB4535288, or can I just slap KB4500181 on top of KB4535288 (which seems like it would overwrite the KB4535288 files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### #TL;DR

There is nothing you currently need to do to get the fixes included in CU4. **They're already there,** even though @@VERSION incorrectly suggests you have a GDR (and, as you've read elsewhere, GDRs do not contain CU fixes). If you want more background, please read on.

### #Background

Patches are *cumulative*, including security updates, which means they include all previous patches in that branch. The size of the (compressed executable) file is not a very reliable way to determine whether or not it includes an earlier patch.

To be clear, each SQL Server release (including each service pack before SQL Server 2017) is what I'll call a "main branch." Once that main branch is released, they later need to enhancements, usually in categories of performance, stability, or security. They release these fixes in the form of GDR and CU updates. These become two separate branches off the main branch:

- The CU branch contains **all fixes** - performance, stability, security. Currently the cadence for these is one a month for the first year of a main branch, and then every other month after that (until that branch is retired, which is longer now than it used to be because their are no service packs making previous service packs obsolete). Once you're on the CU branch, as you apply more updates, you will always be getting **all** the CU fixes. If you apply CU1 and then CU4, you have all the fixes from CU1, CU2, CU3, and CU4. If you apply CU5 and then CU12, you have all the fixes from CU1, CU2, ..., CU11, CU12.
- Sometimes a security release is published out-of-band (meaning not as part of the monthly/bi-monthly CU cadence). This is usually either because the issue is critical or because it needs to be coordinated with a security bulletin that involves other products (like Windows). Like a CU, security updates that apply to a CU branch contain all the fixes from the CU branch up to that point.
- The GDR branch *only* includes **critical fixes**, usually security-related, for the *main branch* (e.g. Service Pack 3). That is the branch I was talking about in the [link referenced below](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/back-to-basics-release-acronyms): I meant that the GDR update for SP3 does not contain any of the CU updates (the post says "critical updates" but I don't have editorial control to fix it).
- The point of the GDR branch is to provide as little surface area changes as possible (because they have to test the impact of all those changes), while still keeping customers safe. Each successive GDR update is just a new build on the GDR branch and so, like CUs and security updates on CU branches, a security update for the GDR branch also contains all the other GDR updates that came before it.
- Except for occasionally early in a release, there are more CU updates than GDR updates, primarily because they're restricted to **critical fixes** and there are just a lot more non-critical fixes over time.

In your case, the (understandable) confusion comes from the fact that @@VERSION returns both CU and GDR in the name, which is nonsensical. When the patch was first released, I complained about this confusion, and after a lengthy debate, they fixed the terminology in the KB articles and other documentation. But it was too late to fix what @@VERSION returns on a build of the engine that was already distributed (and that problem remains today because that was the last update on the CU branch).

That's a lot of background, but to summarize, I can assure you that:

1. The build you have installed is on the CU branch and **is not a GDR update**, in spite of what @@VERSION might be telling you. You need to ignore what that string says because it is wrong but there is no way to fix it.
2. You **definitely** cannot apply CU4 *on top of* KB4535288. The installer will recognize that your version already includes all the fixes in CU4.
3. You do not need to uninstall the security update (which will put you back on whatever build you were on before you applied it), apply CU4 (which will put you on 12.0.6329.1), and reapply the security update (which will put you right back on 12.0.6372.1). **You already have those fixes.**
4. You can choose to not believe me and go ahead and do all of this, I'm just trying to help you avoid work that serves zero purpose, **since you asked the question**. Again, read everything here, but try to *forget* that your @@VERSION incorrectly suggests you are on a GDR build. **You're not.**

---

I had previously said the following, and don't believe I have contradicted myself with anything I've said here:

You can see the list of SQL Server 2014 updates [here](https://sqlperformance.com/latest-builds/sql-server-2014).

In this case, there is nothing you can possibly apply to SQL Server 2014 that will add anything to 12.0.6372.1. Literally nothing. Uninstalling KB4535288 to install CU4 just means you will be ***removing*** the security fix in KB4535288. I see absolutely no reason to do this. And no, you can't just "slap CU4 on top of KB4535288" - well, you can try, but you won't get very far, because the installer will recognize you already have everything in CU4.

Comment: Thanks.  What concerned me was that it says "SP3-CU-GDR" instead of "SP3-CU**4**-GDR".

Comment: @RonJohn IIRC I actually complained about that very label when the patches were released, but not because it doesn't say CU4; the CU in the name indicates it's an update for CU customers (not CU4 only), not for GDR customers (who don't take CUs). I complained about this one because it says both CU and GDR, which used to mean very different things. GDRs usually don't apply to CU branches at all, [as I explained here](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/back-to-basics-release-acronyms). But it wouldn't be Microsoft if they didn't come up with the occasional rule-breaking exception.

Comment: "*I see absolutely no reason to do this.*" I'd have reapplied KB4535288 after KB4500181. :)

Comment: If **all** patches are cumulative, why aren't security patches labeled CU?  More importantly, your linked article says that GDR means "released **without any other critical updates** that have been released for the specific branch", which contradicts the first sentence of your answer, "Patches are cumulative, including security updates, which means **they include all previous patches in that branch**."

Comment: @RonJohn I think you're getting mixed up here **because Microsoft named this specific update incorrectly**. This is an update for the CU branch so, even though it _says_ GDR in the name, it is absolutely most certainly not a GDR update. So let's put anything about GDR aside. Security updates _on a CU branch_, which KB4535288 is, contain all security- and non-security-related patches that have been released to date. You don't need to uninstall KB4535288 to apply CU4 and then re-apply KB4535288 because that will yield _no net changes_.

Comment: @RonJohn On a GDR branch, a security update only contains security updates because, by definition, a GDR branch only contains essential security updates. It's the whole reason a GDR branch exists: so they *don't* have to test all the fixes that get delivered by a CU. If you were on the GDR branch (e.g. have never applied a CU), you would install the GDR version of this update ([KB4532095](https://support.microsoft.com/help/4532095)). This is why you see separate items for CU & GDR [in the main security bulletin](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-0618).

Comment: @RonJohn But on a CU branch, they can't apply security patches to that branch _without_ also bringing forward all the fixes that came before it. Imagine writing a Word document, and saving the original version somewhere. You make a copy, and on that copy, you make a bunch of fixes. Then you want to fix the headline in both documents, but you don't want the original to get all the fixes from the copy. So you change both documents. The original is now equivalent to SP3 with a single GDR update, and the copy is equivalent to SP3 with a CU and an update after that.

Comment: @RonJohn As for why they don't _name_ a CU security update with CU in the name, well, they usually do (at least when they talk about it, as shown in [the security bulletin](https://portal.msrc.microsoft.com/en-us/security-guidance/advisory/CVE-2020-0618)). But you'll have to ask Microsoft about their naming conventions, and why they gave this specific build a version string that includes CU and GDR in it. When I complained about it they fixed the KB article but they couldn't fix what @@VERSION reports. I'm just here trying to help you avoid unnecessary work, but you don't have to believe me.

Comment: "but you don't have to believe me".  Just trying to clarify things; the incorrectly named update is a bit confusing.